# How to activate logo animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I have logo with animation and I want to make it so that when people press some buttons on my website the logo animation plays. My question is how can I have my logo animation activate every time someone press on a button?

Comment: All depends on how you made the animation, so without more details this question is impossible to answer. Take a look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for more info

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: the file is in gif form

<div style="width:100%;height:0adding-bottom:56%osition:relative;"><iframe src="https://giphy.com/embed/cYX1k1ULOXNAyDcc8d" width="100%" height="100%" style="position:absolute" frameBorder="0" class="giphy-embed" allowFullScreen></iframe></div><p><a href="https://giphy.com/gifs/transparent-cYX1k1ULOXNAyDcc8d">via GIPHY</a></p>

Answer (score -1):

Create a button component whit onClick props and using redux to control that props to follow user click on your button component.

After that set your logo runtime even click variable in redux.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not familiar with redux. Is there snippiest for that>

Comment: using react-redux package and see docs . if you familiar the context API in react , redux is very similar that, but redux is powerful in faster changeable variables.